# echo $path is not showing anything else. New laptop

Tags: macos, terminal, path

When I `echo $path`, it is not showing anything. I'm wondering if this what the default should be or not.

sudo `vi /etc/paths` shows the following:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Should anything be showing when I echo $path or is it the appropriate set up?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try $PATH instead of $path??

Comment: Yes! I got /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin